# Status of jobs in gitlab after completion

Tags: gitlab

I have a gitlab pipeline where I have 3 jobs in same stage and should run in parallel. After all jobs are completed, I need to know the following information for each job:
Job Name, Status (pass/fail), started at, finished at

I am using below api in the after_script in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/job?job_token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN"
```

But is always gives me status as 'running'. How can I get the correct status whether the job is passed or failed?

Comment: It seems correct as the `after_script` section is running in the same job. You need to check from these info different job.

Comment: This api doesn't work in different jobs. It gives status of same job.

Comment: Sorry, you can forgot my comment and check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the API in that case.

In `after_script` section, you can use `CI_JOB_STATUS` environment variable (available from Gitlab Runner 13.5). From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) :

> The status of the job as each runner stage is executed. Use with `after_script`. Can be `success`, `failed`, or `canceled`.

Comment: It is not returning anything for me. I wrote echo "$CI_JOB_STATUS" in after_script.

Comment: Could you confirm your gitlab runner version is at least `13.5` ?

Comment: Just checked, it is 12.10.1 :(

Comment: Is it possible to you to upgrade and test ?

Comment: sadly I can't upgrade it :(

Answer (score 0):

I've got "running" from CI_JOB_STATUS

To fix that set ENV variable for job or globally: `FF_USE_LEGACY_KUBERNETES_EXECUTION_STRATEGY: 1`

More details you can find here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27693